# Merge data in one table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables A, B

Table A:

```
ID      Value1   Value2
------------------------
1000     10        25
1001      4        12
1002      2         6
1003      1         8
```

Table B:

```
ID      Value3   Value4
------------------------
1000     51        12
1003      3        10
```

What I need is to show the below result:

```
ID     Value1   Value2   Value3   Value4
-----------------------------------------
1000    10       25       51       12
1001     4       12       NULL     NULL
1002     2        6       NULL     NULL
1003     1        8        3       10
```

The query I've tried:

```
SELECT I.AgentId AS AGENT
    ,COUNT(I.Indice) AS [Number of Inbound calls]
    ,AVG(I.WrapupDuration) AS [AVG Wrapup IN]
    ,COUNT(O.Indice) AS [Number of Out calls]
    ,AVG(O.WrapupDuration) AS [AVG Wrapup Out]
FROM [HN_Ondata].[dbo].[vwInboundCalls] I
LEFT JOIN [HN_Ondata].[dbo].vwOutboundCalls O
    ON I.AgentId = O.AgentId
GROUP BY I.AgentId
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: have you tried anything for this?

Comment: This is an extremely basic SQL concept. Search for some SQL tutorials, and try something yourself before asking us to write your code for you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `LEFT JOIN` and a query like below, you don't need another table:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A A
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @Radu Gheorghiu. Actually am using AVG and count functions, so to get the Value1 am using Count(v1) as Value1, AVG(v2) as Value2... samething for Value3 and Value4.. Im using LEFT join but am not getting the correct values...

Comment: @SiMoKassab Well, post the query you're using and what you want to get as a result.

Comment: this is the query:

`SELECT I.AgentId as AGENT, COUNT(I.Indice) as [Number of Inbound calls], AVG(I.WrapupDuration) as [AVG Wrapup IN], COUNT(O.Indice) as [Number of Out calls], AVG(O.WrapupDuration) as [AVG Wrapup Out] FROM [HN_Ondata].[dbo].[vwInboundCalls] I LEFT JOIN [HN_Ondata].[dbo].vwOutboundCalls O ON I.AgentId=O.AgentId Group by I.AgentId`

For example for the ID 1029 (without LEFT query), i got 4 as Number of Inbound calls, and i got 16 when i use LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `LEFT JOIN` to achieve your goal.

```
SELCT * FROM TABELA LEFT JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @Sadikhasan

Actually am using AVG and count functions, so to get the Value1 am using Count(v1) as Value1, AVG(v2) as Value2... samething for Value3 and Value4..

Im using LEFT join but am not getting the correct values...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `left join`

```
SELECT 
     *
FROM 
     TABLEA T1
LEFT JOIN 
     TABLEB T2 
ON 
     T1.ID = T2.ID
```

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @shaikh Actually am using AVG and count functions, so to get the Value1 am using Count(v1) as Value1, AVG(v2) as Value2... samething for Value3 and Value4.. Im using LEFT join but am not getting the correct values...

Comment: please provide the query.

Comment: `SELECT I.AgentId as AGENT, COUNT(I.Indice) as [Number of Inbound calls],
 AVG(I.WrapupDuration) as [AVG Wrapup IN], 
 COUNT(O.Indice)  as [Number of Out calls],
 AVG(O.WrapupDuration) as [AVG Wrapup Out]

  FROM [HN_Ondata].[dbo].[vwInboundCalls] I LEFT JOIN [HN_Ondata].[dbo].vwOutboundCalls O
  ON I.AgentId=O.AgentId 
   
  Group by I.AgentId `